# build a select query as a gridview datasource asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datasource

I use an asp.net gridview depend on controls to search 
day :   - month :   - year :

in database table I got an startdate field contain the whole date :

I try this query :

```
SELECT        id, shift_id, name_of_shift, person_in_shift, starttime_in_shift, endtime_in_shift, table_id, startdate, enddate, point_id
FROM            sarcshifttable
WHERE         (id IN
                             (SELECT        MIN(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM            sarcshifttable AS sarcshifttable_1
                               GROUP BY table_id)) AND (DATEPART(year, startdate) + '' LIKE @year) AND (DATEPART(day, startdate) + '' LIKE @day) AND (DATEPART(month, startdate) + '' LIKE @month)
```

the controls :

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="day_search" CssClass="textfield NjmeDine_Integer" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="month_search" CssClass="textfield NjmeDine_Integer" Width="40px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="year_search" CssClass="textfield NjmeDine_Integer" Width="80px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

the select parameter :

```
<SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="year_search" DefaultValue="%" Name="year" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="month_search" DefaultValue="%" Name="month" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="day_search" DefaultValue="%" Name="day" PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
```

the startdate in this format : 2014-03-01

note : 
when I try it in database with a static value it's work perfectly

```
SELECT        id, shift_id, name_of_shift, person_in_shift, starttime_in_shift, endtime_in_shift, table_id, startdate, enddate, point_id
FROM            sarcshifttable
WHERE        (DATEPART(month, startdate) + '' LIKE 03) AND (id IN
                             (SELECT        MIN(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM            sarcshifttable AS sarcshifttable_1
                               GROUP BY table_id)) AND (DATEPART(year, startdate) + '' LIKE 2014) AND (DATEPART(day, startdate) + '' LIKE 01) AND (DATEPART(month, startdate) + '' LIKE 03)
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is :

```
    SELECT        id, shift_id, name_of_shift, person_in_shift, starttime_in_shift, endtime_in_shift, 

SELECT        id, shift_id, name_of_shift, person_in_shift, starttime_in_shift, endtime_in_shift, table_id, startdate, enddate, point_id
FROM            sarcshifttable
WHERE        (DATEPART(month, startdate) + '' LIKE 03) AND (id IN
                             (SELECT        MIN(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM            sarcshifttable AS sarcshifttable_1
                               GROUP BY table_id)) AND ((DATEPART(year, startdate) + '' LIKE '%'+@year+'%') AND (DATEPART(day, startdate) + '' LIKE '%'+@day+'%') AND (DATEPART(month, startdate) + '' LIKE '%'+@month+'%')
```